# User input in HTML form not captured in Python correctly

Tags: python, html, templates, flask

i have this html form where user can choose name from a list :

```
{% block main %}

    <form action="/ballot" method="post">
        1st Choice
            <select name="name1">
            <option disabled selected value="">name</option>
            {% for candidate in candidates %}
                <option value={{ candidate }}>{{ candidate["name"] }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
            </select><div></div>
```

In python, i request for this data "name1" using this code

```
 name1= request.form['name1']           
 return "Username is " + name1
```

And the result is below :
Username is {'id':

Note that "{'id':" is nowhere in my code

How do i get the correct value from html form

Comment: try printing the contents of request.form it should have all the data entered in the post form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your for loop value must be between ":

Try editing from this

```html
<option value={{ candidate }}>{{ candidate["name"] }}</option>
```

To this:

```html
<option value="{{ candidate }}">{{ candidate["name"] }}</option>
```

Comment: it shows me the name now but also other things :                                                 
        Username is {'id': 1, 'name': 'amy', 'points': 0}

Comment: without any more context its hard to help you more. Where it "shows" the new data, how are you accesing it, please be clear when you ask, Try to bring the minimal context possible to understand what you are doing and what you are trying to do.

Comment: figured out already, thanks for the help!